# V7 Preference Custom layout with dynamic height?

Tags: android, android-layout, preferencefragment

I'm working on create a few custom preferences for a settings screen i'm building.  The Layout's are fairly straight forward, two text views and an image view.  I want the textviews to wrap and the preference view to grow based on the contents inside. Ignore the constraints for now I want this set up with a constraint layout but originally I thought I might have been doing something wrong there so went to a basic relative layout while I troubleshoot.

I've set up a couple different basic layouts but it seems like there might be a max height that can't easily be overridden?

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/motivatingTitleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_motivating_photo_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/motivatingMessageTextView"
    android:layout_below="@id/motivatingTitleTextView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_motivating_photo_message"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/motivatingTitleTextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the settings xml

```
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Notifications and Access">

    <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="allowPushNotifications"
        android:title="Notifications"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>

<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Personalization">

    <com.company.Settings.AddMotivatingPhotoPreference/>
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>
```

Finally The Preference Fragment
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat
{

```
public SettingsFragment()
{
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey)
{
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
}
}
```

[image]

EDIT:

So I found out if I use a layout tag inside a default Preference object it lays out correctly.  I can make this work, but I would prefer to be able to create my own custom classes so that I can separate additional logic into them.  Has anyone done that before or have an example?  I feel like I must just be missing something simple...

```
<android.support.v7.preference.Preference
        android:layout="@layout/preference_add_motivating_photo"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why I didn't think of this at the time but the answer is to create a custom preference like above and then use the layout property in the xml for my layout.  Simple enough.